# how to calculate power consumption by a power transistor

Tags: transistors

How can I calculate power consumption by a power transistor or what is the formula to calculate power consumption by amplifying transistor during its amplification action? That is a Vcc supply, not an input signal.

Comment: Voltage across times current through, same as always.

Comment: I think you're talking about the device's quiescent current. Try looking at the data sheet, there may be a value for that.

Answer (score 1):

Power = Voltage × Current
Power = Vce × Ic 
Vce= voltage accros the transistor 
Ic = collector current of transistor

Comment: Going one step further: Assuming you are driving the transistor with a sinusoid, maximum power consumption occurs at the midpoint of the sinusoid.  Proving this requires basic calculus.  The exercise is VERY worthwhile.